# TypeError: Object of type '_Serializer' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, api

I am newer in Django rest api. My code is bellow:

```
class PatientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Patient.objects.all()
serializer_class = PatientSerializer
filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
filterset_fields = ['id', 'email', 'mobile', 'status', 'type', 'gender']
ordering_fields = ['id', 'name']

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    status = self.request.query_params.get('status')
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name')
    if not status:
        queryset = queryset.exclude(status="DELETE")
    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=name)
    return queryset

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    patient = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = PatientSerializer(patient)

    summary = dict()
    summary['payment'] = list(PatientPayment.objects.filter(patient_id=pk).aggregate(Sum('amount')).values())[0]
    summary['appointment'] = DoctorAppointment.objects.filter(patient_id=pk).count()

    d_appoint = DoctorAppointment.objects.filter(patient__id=pk).last()
    appoint_data = DoctorAppointmentSerializer(d_appoint)

    summary['last_appointment'] = appoint_data

    content = {"code": 20000, "data": serializer.data, "summary": summary}
    return Response(content)
```

Here url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/patients/2/
```

When I run in postman it getting the error bellow:

> TypeError at /api/patients/2/
>   Object of type 'DoctorAppointmentSerializer' is not JSON serializable

Here problem with the code snippet:

```
d_appoint = DoctorAppointment.objects.filter(patient__id=pk).last()
appoint_data = DoctorAppointmentSerializer(d_appoint)
```

My question is how can I getting my result?

DoctorAppointmentSerializer Class:

```
class DoctorAppointmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
patient = PatientSerializer(read_only=True)
patient_id = serializers.IntegerField()
doctor = DoctorSerializer(read_only=True)
doctor_id = serializers.IntegerField()
doc_image = Base64ImageField(
    allow_null=True, max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False
)
doc_file = Base64ImageField(
    allow_null=True, max_length=None, use_url=True, required=False
)

class Meta:
    model = DoctorAppointment
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'problem', 'age', 'gender', 'description', 'doctor', 'doctor_id', 'patient',
              'patient_id', 'advice', 'doc_image', 'doc_file', 'created_at']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the **`.data`** property of **`DoctorAppointmentSerializer`** class

```
appoint_data = DoctorAppointmentSerializer(d_appoint).data
                                                  ^^^^^^
```